# Calling Android VNC from my App with pre-configurations

Tags: android, vnc

I want to call Android VNC from my own app ...

But I want the android VNC configurations ( ip / password / ... ) to be configured in the code

Just when clicking the VNC icon im my app, I see the desktop of my laptop directly ..

I searched and found that this piece of code can be used for calling any app ..

but still confused .. How to call android vnc by this way ..

Also, How to set the configurations in the code ..

code :

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package");
startActivity(intent);
```

Can anyone help ???

Comment: When you contacted the authors of whatever VNC app you wish to use, and asked them if they support any `Intent` extras for this sort of configuration, what did they tell you?

Comment: Indeed, I did not contact any authors .. What do you advise me ?? How can I contact them ???

Comment: "How can I contact them ?" -- contact information, such as their Web site, can be found on the app's listing in the Play Store.